# Why aren't changes in an object able to be written into a file?

Tags: java, object, serialization, file-io, deserialization

I am trying to write the same object to a file twice. However, changing a value in the object does not seem to change what is written to the file.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("file.txt"));
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("file.txt"));

        MyObj obj = new MyObj();

        obj.val = 1;
        oos.writeObject(obj);

        obj.val = 2;
        oos.writeObject(obj);

        System.out.println( ((MyObj)ois.readObject()).val );
        System.out.println( ((MyObj)ois.readObject()).val );

        oos.close();
        ois.close();
}
```

MyObj implementation:

```java
class MyObj implements Serializable  {
    int val;
}
```

Since `obj.val` is `1` when I write `obj` to the file for the first time and `2` the second time, I am expecting the program to print `1` then `2`. However, I get `1` printed both times instead.

Why is this the case, and what can I do to get around this?

Comment: Each object will only be written once. You can use `writeUnshared` if you don't want that behaviour.

Comment: Thanks a ton!! Are there any potential drawbacks I should be aware of when using `writeUnshared` rather than `writeObject`?

Comment: Object graphs are written, so writeUnshared has the potential to write more data if your objects share dependent objects.